# Objective C error 3840 - bad JSON apparently but it validates with JSlint

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I have read around and this error seems to be from bad JSON.  Easy enough, here is my JSON

{"year":"2012","wheels":"Standard","trans":"Unknown"}

My issue is, this appears to be correct, and when I run it through JSON lint it returns vaild.  I have also used cURL to download this page and used json_decode() to read it...worked fine.

Here is an example page: http://drivingthenation.com/app/carlist/getVinDtn.php?v=JA3215H1*C*******M&f=v

I ran it through HTTPScoop and the only thing the response text returned was

{"year":"2012","wheels":"Standard","trans":"Unknown"}

On the objective-c end I am using NSURL and NSData to get the URL, and then NSJSONSerialization.  I can print out before NSJSONSerialization and see that it is infact getting data, but this error only occurs when I try to format it into JSON.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSJSONSerialization class, by default, expects the input to be not just valid JSON, but a valid JSON *object*. If you want to read something that's not an object, you need to specify the [NSJSONReadingAllowFragments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSJSONReadingOptions) option to the reader.

Comment: Okay, I tried that.  My code is now :  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error]

Now I am getting "invalid value around character 0"

Comment: There seems to be some error with the way the URL is fetched.  I made a seperate file called get.php that uses cURL to output JSON from a specific file, rather than using the URL to get information.  So I think this means I need to use POST requests versus GET requests just due to the nature of the data I am sending? (Vin numbers)

Comment: @AustinWolff: I can't imagine why that would make a difference. Are you sure the data isn't corrupt in some way, like invisible junk characters at the end?

Comment: Yes.  I verified the response data with HTTPScoop.  My iOS app now uses POST instead of GET and it works correctly.